# Finding solution on authorization token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a task on sending a link with a unique token to confirm order.
When user click on that link, they will be redirected to a webpage which takes the token to get order detail, and then shows the button for user to confirm order.

There are 2 persons:

- Mr. A: can click on the link and can confirm order.
- Mr. B: has no permission to confirm order, just can follow email.

It will be sent to Mr. A and CC to Mr. B

Mr. B will receive that link and try to click it, the same as Mr A.
So how to detect who clicked on that token?

I have a solution that sending other email only to Mr. A with a unique code. And when he is redirected to the webpage, he has to enter that unique code before confirming order.
Mr. B doesn't receive that unique code email so he cannot do anything.

Could you guys have any other solution to detect from where that link was clicked? I just wanna send only 1 email with the token.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are sending a secure key of any kind (for confirmation) via email, then it needs to have a short lifespan and it should _never_ be cc'd to anyone. You are correct to not cc Mr. B. at all. What is your requirement? (Also consider asking security.stackexchange.com for security questions too.)

Comment: Can you do like change the token for user once it is clicked. So, next time same link will be visited, it check for the unique id that is already changed. May be it resolve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't sure that Mr. A clicks the link before Mr. B. They often send a security code via SMS, like Banking system. However I'm finding other solution, so that I only need to send 1 email (changing token or add some script into the link to verify who click on it)